# Create logcat filters for all applications

Tags: android, android-studio

I have few standard filters that I have created for my app's logs. I use **same format** of logs for **all of my apps**. I want these filters to be available in **every project** I create with android studio e.g. `Firebase` filter available for all projects.

Is it possible to create these filter once and use them in all of my apps?

**PS:**

I have created a bash function which creates a logcat filter for any project by picking the project ID from `build.gradle` file.

> I don't like it as I need to open separate console for it.

I just want filters in Android Studio.

```
function filterLog(){
  TAG=`grep applicationId < app/build.gradle | sed 's/.*applicationId.*\.//' | tr -d '"'`
  printf "filtering tag = %s\n" $TAG
  adb shell logcat -c && adb shell logcat -v raw  $TAG:D *:S
} # filterLog
```

[image: firebase filter]

Comment: Let me update the question.

Comment: @Enzokie have a look now.

Comment: any answer? ....